# What does a polynomial look like under projection of underlying space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Consider a multivariate polynomial in $F:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow\Bbb R$, $F\in\Bbb R[x,y,z]$ with prescribed values over a sphere in $\Bbb R^3$.

Consider standard Riemann projection from $\Bbb R^3\rightarrow\Bbb R^2$ that maps $1-1$ all points on a sphere in $\Bbb R^3$ except north pole to $\Bbb R^2$. Now, the polynomial that was defined in $\Bbb R^3$ could be defined as a rational function from $\Bbb R^2\rightarrow\Bbb R$.

What does the projected rational function $F_\pi\in\Bbb R(u,v)$ look like? For instance its degree information (define $\mathsf{deg(\frac{f}g)=deg(f) + deg(g)}$)?

In general we could take a multivariate polynomial $F:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R$ and look at series of projections on spheres from $\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R^{n-1}\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow\Bbb R^2\rightarrow\Bbb R$ with certain values prescribed over sphere in $\Bbb R^n$. What does the final univariate rational function look like?

> Note that after we project from $\Bbb R^3\rightarrow\Bbb R^2$, the points on sphere could be thought as lying on concentric circles on $\Bbb R^2$. So when we project from $\Bbb R^2\rightarrow\Bbb R^1$ to get univariate rational function, you have to project from many different north poles.

We could also look at a converse picture from univariate to multivariate lifting with values of univaritae polynomial fixed at certain points with lifted values restricted to spheres. What will corresponding multivariate polynomial look like? For instance total degree information?

---

Suppose you pick $N_1+N_2$ points on the sphere in $\Bbb R^n$ with a minimum multivariate polynomial $P$ taking some prescribed values on $N_1$ set of points while another minimum $Q$ taking some prescribed values on $N_2$ set of points. These minimum total degree $degP,degQ$ polynomials are projected down to univariate rational functions. We interpolate minimally to get another univariate rational function $R_\pi$ that takes same value as univariate rational functions $P_\pi,R_\pi$ on prescribed projected points. When we lift $R_\pi$ back to $\Bbb R^n$, what will be its multivariate total degree in terms of total degrees of $P,Q$, $degP,degQ$? Could $degR$ be upper bounded by $degP degQ$?

Comment: What makes you so sure that the projected function is still a polynomial? Try going through the formula Greg Martin linked to.

Comment: so we get rational functions?

Answer (score 1):

The "standard Riemann projection" you refer to is also called [stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Definition), and its formula is well known. So your resulting function from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ will be a composition of the inverse stereographic projection and the function you started with on the 3-sphere.

Comment: sorry could you provide more details?

Comment: @Turbo: Could you be more specific? What details would you like to see?

Comment: @RghtHndSd answer to degree question?

Answer (score 1):

We essentially have 
$$
f_\pi(u,v) = f(x, y, \pm\sqrt{1 - (x^2 + y^2)})
$$ 
where $u$ and $v$ are the points corresponding to the tuple $(x, y, \pm\sqrt{1 - (x^2 + y^2)})$ under the stereographic projection.

This is given by the following:
$$
f_\pi(u, v) = f\left(\frac{2u}{1 + u^2 + v^2}, \frac{2v}{1 + u^2 + v^2}, \frac{-1 + u^2 + v^2}{1 + u^2 + v^2}\right).
$$

So in general the resulting function will be a rational function, not a polynomial. Of course we can extend the grading of polynomials to that of rational functions, by $\deg{f/g} = \deg{f} - \deg{g}$, so that a generic polynomial under this mapping will have either positive powers of a degree $-1$ variable (the degree of $x, y$ under the projection) or of a degree $0$ one (the degree of $z$).

Now for the projection to the single variable. Notice that since the projection to the line from the circle only cares about the values of the original function around the equator of the unit sphere, which already lies in the plane, the composition of projections is actually trivial. Indeed:
$$
f_{\pi\pi}(w) = f_\pi\left(\frac{2w}{w^2 + 1}, \frac{w^2 - 1}{w^2 + 1}\right) \\
 = f\left(u, v, 0\right)\\
= f\left( \frac{2w}{w^2 + 1}, \frac{w^2 - 1}{w^2 + 1}, 0 \right).
$$
So the composition of projections is obtained by ignoring the projection to the plane and projecting straight from the equator to the line. Note that of course this must occur in higher dimensions simply by analogy. Again, in this case, we have powers of a degree $-1$ or a degree $0$ variable.

Of course, since the projection is invertible, the preimage $g^\pi(x, y, z)$ on the unit sphere of some $g(x, y)$ on the plane is well-defined and unique. Less immediate is its extention to the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, equivalent to the condition for equivalence of projections from two different initial polynomial functions, but a little thought shows that clearly $f_{\pi} = g_{\pi}$ iff 
$$
f(x, y, z) = g(x, y, z) + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (r_3^n - 1) h_n(x, y, z)
$$
for some functions $h_n$, where $r_3^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is the radius.

Similarly, we have $f_{\pi\pi} = g_{\pi\pi}$ iff
$$
f(x, y, z) = g(x, y, z) + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty z^n h_n(x, y, z) + \sum_{n = 1}
^\infty (r_2^n - 1) h'_n(x, y, z)
$$
for some functions $h_n, h'_n$, where $r_2^2 = x^2 + y^2$.

That is, in both cases, they belong to the equivalence class of functions whose difference vanishes on the relevant set we are projecting from. Obvious once you think about it.

Comment: ". Notice that since the projection to the line from the circle only cares about the values of the original function around the equator of the unit sphere" I do not think this is true.

Comment: In what sense? If you compose the stereographic projection from the sphere to the plane with the projection from the circle to the line, then it is equal to the projection from the sphere's equator to the line.

Comment: Please see updates in question. Imagine projecting an higher dim cube to real line.

Comment: The stereographic projection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$ is defined on the unit circle only. There is no notion of 'many north poles'. Are you asking for some kind of averaged projection, like an integral over a ray passing through many suchcircles?

Comment: Consider 8 vertex cube in R^3. When you project from north pole of sphere enclosing cube (assuming north pole middle of a face and top of it), your 8 vertices land on two squares each enclosed by a circle (concentric circles). We need to project there 8 points on the line. May be we can take outer circle's north pole, then projection of interior points have messier coordinates.

Comment: Fitting a cube into the unit sphere and keeping track of its vertices does indeed result in two squares inscribed in two concentric circles *in the plane*. But the next projection, from the plane to the line, requires picking a circle and projecting from that. Sure, we can pick the outer of the two concentric circles, and indeed the four vertices of its inscribed square go to the line, but the other four vertices on the smaller circle *are not projected*, because one cannot project stereographically from the entire plane to the line. One *must* restrict to points on a single circle to project.

Comment: True. So let us call this a mock stereographic projection. All we care about is 1-1 map.